Power BI Change Spacing Between Chart Columns
I have a simple cluster chart with 13 bars and can't add spacing between the bars (while keeping the same bar width) so that everything isn't squished together.  I know there used to be an inner padding function in Power BI that no longer exists.  (BTW the issue persists even when I remove the negative total in the chart, so it's not that).  Thoughts?


your question is similar to this one. Please check if the solution for you as well.
enter link description here

That suggestion includes using columns, but my current Y-axis are all measures, so not sure how to adapt for that.

The 4 columns in the suggestions are all measures. If you have 10 measures, then create a table with 10 rows. Then use switch to apply measures to each row.
